# Angular *ngIf with async pipe inner condtion based on the resulting model

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I'd be a happy man if someone could explain why the following is not working as expected please?
The `hasCreative` is a boolean but regardless of its true/false value, the `<li>` is always displayed. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="uiModel$ | async as model">
    <ul class="nav" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
      <li *ngIf="model.hasCreative" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['']">Home</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</ng-container>

export class UserInterfaceModel {
  hasCreative: boolean;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserInterfaceService {
  user: CognitoUser;
  userLoggedIn = false;
  private userInterfaceModelSubject$: Subject<UserInterfaceModel> = new Subject();
  userInterfaceModel$ = this.userInterfaceModelSubject$.asObservable();

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    combineLatest([this.authService.onUserLoaded$]).subscribe(([currentUser]) => {
      this.user = currentUser;
      this.userLoggedIn = true;
      this.buildUserInterfaceModel();
    });
  }

  buildUserInterfaceModel(){
    const model = new UserInterfaceModel();
    if (this.userLoggedIn && this.user !== null){
      model.hasCreative  = this.user.getSignInUserSession().getIdToken().payload.creative;
    }
    this.userInterfaceModelSubject$.next(model);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the uiModel$ content?

Comment: I can only see this happening if `model.hasCreative = 'false'`, instead of `model.hasCreative = false`

Comment: uiModel$: Observable<UserInterfaceModel>;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private authService: AuthService, private userInterfaceService: UserInterfaceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.uiModel$ = this.userInterfaceService.userInterfaceModel$;
  }

Comment: export class UserInterfaceModel {
  hasCreative: boolean;
}

Comment: @Nevnev can you update your answer with how you `UserInterfaceModel` instance looks like. Because it's obvious the `model.hasCreative` is resolving to `true`. So it's either a string, or something else, but definitely not `false`

Comment: Thanks, hopefully i've added enough code to explain it's origin. I've edited the original post

Comment: @Nevnev do `console.log(model.hasCreative)` right after you assign it, and post the result here.

Comment: if the token is set to true, console.log displays true and setting the token to false, console.log displays false. Apologies, this is a real pain. Maybe there is something else incredibly stupid in my code thats causing it

Comment: Actually hold that thought. Rather than take the token value, I've hard coded the response to true and it worked! And setting it directly to false also worked the opposite way. Very strange. You pinpointed the problem area so thanks very much for your help. I'll update the code with the exact fix soon.

Comment: the token attribute i've set to be a string and changed the code to something like this so i know exactly what value/type im dealing with and it works. - model.hasCreative = isCreative.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false;

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="uiModel$ | async as model; else loading">
    <ul class="nav" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
      <li *ngIf="model.hasCreative === true " class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['']">Home</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  Loading stuff...
</ng-template>
```

If `loading` template will render it means your `Observable` has no value. If it dosnt work too, try render the value of `model.hasCreative` by adding somethin like this:

```html
<span>{{model.hasCreative}}<span>
```

out of `<ul>` tag to see if `model.hasCreative` has `true/false` value or not.

Comment: Thanks, i did try that and the span renders as true or false depending on what it is

Comment: is your problem fixed?

Comment: thanks yes. I changed the way i set isCreative and it worked.

Comment: model.hasCreative = isCreative.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false;

Comment: So, it was a `string`. you said it's a `boolean` while it wasn't.

Comment: Either side it was a boolean, server and client but in AWS world, the true/false wasn't being translated or at least not working. So the fix was to set it as a string in AWS world and then i would know for sure what is was and make the check. Anyway, I'll take it so i can move on. Thanks for helping.